# typescript を emacs で記述する際に利用できるパッケージは何ですか？

Tags: emacs, typescript

typescript (`.ts`) のファイルを emacs で編集する際に、利用できるパッケージは何ですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/typescript/README.html

spacemacs でデフォルトで利用される環境バックエンドフレームワークは tide であり、 [tide は `typescript-mode` を利用している様子です](https://github.com/ananthakumaran/tide#use-package)。

なので、[`typescript-mode`](https://github.com/emacs-typescript/typescript.el) を利用するのが良さそうだ、と思っています。